# MS Graph API Group which contains a Plan

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-planner, microsoft-graph-plannertasks, microsoft-graph-groups

Basically I want to know which group contains the plan I am using. I know how to get which plans are in a group:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{group-id}/planner/plans
```

But not, given a plan, how to know which group contains it.

Why do I need it? Because I have a plan, with its planner tasks, and I want to add a comment in it programatically. To add a comment we must do this:

```
POST /groups/{id}/conversations/{id}/threads
```

So, I need the GroupId, but I only have the PlanId (well, and the Plan object).

Does anybody know how can I get the GroupId from the Plan?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Beta, Plan has a `container` property. Looking at that you can tell when the Plan is in a group (vs. something else) and the id of the group. You also get the URL to the group itself. Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannerplan?view=graph-rest-beta
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/plannerplancontainer?view=graph-rest-beta

In V1. The group id is available in the `owner` property of the plan. However, please note that we're deprecating this property in favor of the `container` property from beta, since a single id is not capable of expressing different kinds of objects that can contain a Plan anymore. So I'd highly recommend using the beta API for the Plan, and not take a dependency on the `owner`. In V1, if the plan is not contained by a group, trying to get a group with the value of `owner` property will result in a 404.